# Save from overwriting large number of values by parallel calls without messing the code

Tags: c#

```
class abc {

  string value1 = "", value2 = "", ........... valueN = "";

    #region Methods

    public void method1(DataSet dataSet) {
            populate valueS using populateValues() and use it for doing something
       }

    ....

    public void methodN(DataSet dataSet) {
            populate valueS using populateValues() and use it for doing something else
       }

    #endregion

  public void populateValues(DataSet dataSet) {

    #region populate valueS so they can be used by methodS

    if(dataSet.Tables.Contains("Table1") {
        var dataRow1 = dataSet.Tables["Table1"].Select();
        if(dataRow1.Length > 0) {
            value1 = dataRow1[0]["value1"].ToString()
            }
        }

    .....

    if(dataSet.Tables.Contains("TableN") {
        var dataRowN = dataSet.Tables["TableN"].Select();
        if(dataRowN.Length > 0) {
            valueN = dataRowN[0]["valueN"].ToString()
            }
        }
    #endregion
    }

  }
```

The above snippet is an abstract skeleton of a large legacy project in which there are many `methodS()` like:

- `method1()`
- `method2()`
- .....
- `methodN()`

Almost all of these require *almost all* `valueS`:

- `value1`
- `value2`
- ...
- `valueN`

which are populated using `populateValues()`.

This is how `abc` is used in other places:

```
class xyz {
    abc a = new abc();

  public void doingSomething() {

    //Get data from DB and populate to dataSet

    a.method1();
    a.method5();
    ....
    }

  public void doingSomethingElse() {

    //Get data from DB and populate to dataSet

    a.method1();

    return;
    }
}
```

`doingSomething()` is part of a web service project which is mostly called at the same time from few overlapping-lu running windows service projects.

I'm seeing a danger of possible overwriting of `valueS` by `populateValues()` when any of the `methodS()` are called in parallel.

The structure of `dataSet` is mostly unpredictable and hence I always need to check the `Table1` existence.

The methods will mostly be called in parallel as they're part of a web services project.

> How do I save myself from overwriting these large number of values without messing the code in C#?

In other words, how do we make sure that the `valueS` set after `methodN()` is not passed to `methodN+1()` when they're called simultaneously?

The most safe approach would be to copy pasted entire `populateValues()` body in each `methodS()` however, this will mess the project a lot.

Comment: Solution 1: Don't call any of the methods in parallel, or, if you call them from separate threads, introduce locks which will enforce this sequential call pattern. Solution 2: Refactor the class to not have shared state but instead work out its state locally, separate the state from the class containing the methods so that each method can get its own local state from the data set.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The methods will mostly be called in parallel as they're part of a web services project. Can you elaborate with some kind of a skeleton like I have shown in my question please?

Comment: No, your class is borked for a parallel world. You simply cannot fix this easily. Refactor it to not have shared state, or to enfore sequential call patterns, or to use distinct instances per request.

Comment: Are you sharing object instances between requests, or only one instance per request?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I understand. How do you **refactor** a class to not have **shared state**? How do you **enforce sequential call patterns**? I'm looking freezed with this problem. I'll update my question to show how I call the methods.

Comment: You should look into the answer provided by Anil, create a separate class to hold the state, create a method that can take the data set and create an object of this class, populating it with data, then use that object in the method. If you need to call other methods using the same data, refactor those methods to use the state object instead of a dataset.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, I'm reading it and trying to understand how it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a class having all Values

```
Class resultVals
{

    string value1 = "", value2 = "", ........... valueN = "";

}
```

Modify populateValues to return new class `resultVals`.

```
public resultVals populateValues(DataSet dataSet) {

 resultVals valueS =new  resultVals() ;


#region populate valueS so they can be used by methodS

if(dataSet.Tables.Contains("Table1") {
    var dataRow1 = dataSet.Tables["Table1"].Select();
    if(dataRow1.Length > 0) {
        valueS.value1 = dataRow1[0]["value1"].ToString()
        }
    }

.....

if(dataSet.Tables.Contains("TableN") {
    var dataRowN = dataSet.Tables["TableN"].Select();
    if(dataRowN.Length > 0) {
        valueS.valueN = dataRowN[0]["valueN"].ToString()
        }
    }
#endregion
}
return resultVals ;
```

}

Use the returned value (`resultVals`) in all methods.

```
public void method1(DataSet dataSet) {
             resultVals valueS = populateValues() 
            and use it for doing something
       }
```

Comment: How does it solve the problem of overwriting? I see that `methodS()` may still be able to share `resultVals`. Can you please specify it more?

Comment: Updated my answer to return the resultVals.

Comment: Understood, it looks like the problem is poor design. Accepted as answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to synchronize **populateValues**

```
lock(new object())
{
    var result = populateValues();
}
```

However, lock is the simplest one. There are others. ex, you can use Monitor class as well.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the fields from the abc class. 
Remove populate values method. 
Create extension method to get value by a number.
Use the extension in place of the valueN field (easily regexp replaced in the code file).

```
public static string GetValue(this DataSet dataSet, int n)
{
    if (dataSet.Tables.Contains("Table" + n) 
    {
        var dataRow = dataSet.Tables["Table" + n].Select();
        if (dataRow.Length > 0) 
        {
            return = dataRow[0]["value" + n].ToString()
        }
    }

    return string.Empty;
}


public void method1(DataSet dataSet) 
{
    var value1 = dataSet.GetValue(1);
}
```

Better yet, combine this with the Anil's answer and use a struct

```
public struct Values
{
    public string value1;
    ...
    public string valueN;

    public static Values Init(DataSet dataSet)
    {
        // populate values logic here (use the extension from above)
        value1 = dataSet.GetValue(1);
         ...
        valueN = dataSet.GetValue(N);
    }
}
```

And then call the methods.

```
var dataSet = new DataSet();
var values = Values.Init(dataSet);

a.method1(values);
a.method5(values);

public void method1(Values values)
{
    // use values.value1 instead of value1 here
}
```